# 'file' slot name does not exist in the object of the 'RasterStack' class when use writeRaster() in R

Tags: r-raster

When I used writeRaster() in R, I got the error like this: Error in .startGDALwriting(x, filename, gdal = options, ...): 'file' slot name does not exist in the object of the 'RasterStack' class.

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384275/2418532

Comment: @Sergio, thank you for your reply. I tried raster(stack) to convert the stack to a raster first, but it showed the converted raster had no value. I used brick(stack) instead and used writeRaster() after, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I created a raster stack with the raster package

```
raster_stack <- stack(DEM,SLP,TWI,AHS,LSF,CNBL,RSP)
```

But it was not able to write the raster stack in my file:

```
writeRaster(raster_stack, "Cov_Stack.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
```

> Error in .startGDALwriting(x, filename, gdal = options, ...) :
> formal argument "sources" matched by multiple actual arguments

So I used the terra package.

```
test <- rast(raster_stack)
terra::writeRaster(Test, "Cov_Stack.tif")
```

It's simple but I hope it helps you.